# Mocking a Source in Akka Streams

Tags: scala, mockito, akka-stream

I have a wrapper class `AwsS3Bucket` which when invoked, returns a source `Source[ByteString, NotUsed]`. In my unit test case, I have mocked this client and do the necessary assertions.

```
val source = Source.fromIterator(() => List(ByteString("some string")).toIterator)
when(awsS3Bucket.getSource(any[String])).thenReturn(source)
```

However, now I want to test the error scenario wherein I want the `getSource` method to throw an exception. 
I tried the following code,

```
val error = new RuntimeException("error in source")
when(awsS3Bucket.getSource(any[String])).thenReturn(error)
```

but it gives me a compilation issue saying that

```
Cannot resolve overloaded method thenReturn
```

Can anyone please let me know the correct method of returning an exception in a Source in akka streams.

Comment: Just why? A fixture/test `Source` can easily be prepared from `Iterable[ByteString]`, no need to mock

Comment: @cchantep he seems to be mocking the component that returns the `Source`, not the source itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `thenThrow(new RuntimeException("error in source"))` to stub an `Exception`.

That said, you may find issues sometimes with checked exceptions as Scala treats all exceptions as runtime, so they aren't declared in the signature, and standard Mockito will validate you're stubbing an exception that can be thrown by the stubbed method.

In [mockito-scala](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala) that check has been removed to acknowledge the fact that all exceptions behave as runtime in Scala